# Display time and date in this format

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently getting the date and time from my database in this format 2019-01-17 10:20:00. Is it possible to change this format to 17 January 2019 10.20 pm to display? I am Using ajax call in JS to retrieve the data. Any help available? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `toUTCString()`

```js
console.log(new Date('2019-01-17 10:20:00').toUTCString())
```

Comment: Not recommended to pass non valid ISO formatted strings to `new Date`. Will get inconsistent results across different environments